# Am I being too perfectionist?

Tags: stress, review

I work in a incentive payment area in a big telecommunication company, our work is to calculate the incentive compensation to some people related to the company depending on their sales. Sometimes the calculation is hard and data is not always clean, and sometimes I found mistakes in a calculation that should have been detected months ago. I always try to solve it as well as I can.

However, sometimes resolving those mistakes is so difficult that even bosses don't want to pay attention because no one cares (when calculation is for example 4 months old). I once heard my boss saying that higher position bosses know that we have a margin error due to complex calculations.

Is it ok to be like this? I recently found some mistakes in my friend's calculation but they don't seem to care and nothing happened (even audit came and all was fine).

Am I being too perfectionist? Or I should I understand that there are margins for errors? If I find an error in a calculation related to, for example, December 2020, should I review all the 2020's calculations (which obviously requires a lot of time)?

Comment: Choose your battles wisely: Not all mistakes are equal. You should only go after this if the errors are systematic (i.e. to don't average out over time) and are big enough to matter or have legal impacts.

Comment: Are the beneficiaries complaining? How much is the error in cash?

Comment: What makes you think the input to your calculations is "100% accurate?" You can expect inconsistencies between different people or departments reporting facts about the same event, not to mention sales staff deliberately reporting end-of-accounting period results "early" to get "next month's bonus now, not in a month's time".

Comment: the error in cash is around $15 dollar for high position sellers. during 4 month period

Answer (score 15):

In business, everything is cost vs benefits.

> However, sometimes resolving those mistakes is so difficult that even bosses doesnt want to pay attention because no one cares (when calculation is like for example 4 months, because it is old). I once hear my boss saying that higher position bosses know that we have a margin error due to hard calculation.

This is where perfectionism can be a liability instead of an asset.  If a mistake is costing the company $100,000 per year, but fixing it will cost 10 million, the company will take the $100,000 hit, as it would take 100 years to break even, assuming that the problem did not fix itself, or become irrelevant in that time.  If an error has been in place for 4 months as in  your example, it could be VERY expensive to go back and refactor all the calculations, then all of the calculations downstream of the calculations based on that error, compounding the cost of correction.

Now, there's nothing wrong with spotting and correcting errors where practical, but from a business standpoint, if the fix costs more than the error, they will tolerate the error.

Going forward, continue to document what you find, but take your lead from your team and bosses.  If they are not concerned about it, leave it be.   Reporting what you find to them is being responsible, but that is where your responsibility ends.

Comment: And before you say "it didn't cost anything for me to fix the error", remember that your time has value too. If you spend an hour fixing the error, that's an hour you weren't working on something else. If your boss considers that something else to be more important than the error, then fixing it is a detriment to your company.

Comment: So many times this. Also, you might uncover things that best remain hidden. I once worked somewhere, where they discovered they'd been underpaying some clients for years. A new system was put in, and it started raising questions from those testing it 'why are our payments now X+3 instead of X as we were getting before, when nothing else has changed?'. It was 'fixed' for everyone else by telling them it was a new charging system if I remember correctly. Maybe not legal, but it happened.

Comment: @djsmiley2kStaysInside I remember an "error" I found and pushed too hard on when I was young, dumb and inexperienced.  I was told to forget about it.  Not too long afterwards, I was told that my services would no longer be required.  A few years later, I  met a man who had worked at the same company, and he also mentioned that he found a similar "error", and he too was told that his services were no longer required.  No legal action was ever taken, but we compared notes and drew some interesting conclusions.

Answer (score 1):

OK quite a few questions here but the main ones I think are:

> Am I being too perfectionist?

and

> Or I should I understand that there are margin errors?

So to answer you first question you've brought this up before with the management (hopefully in email) and they have said they are happy with a few mistakes here and there. Also the auditors are happy so as long as it's not illegal then I would say leave it.

In terms of the next question it's perfectly normal for there to be a margin of error with any calculation. Even academic papers will list their margin of error so again this is something that you must understand.

The question here is what is a reasonable margin of error and officially that's a management decision here you can help them calculate that and give advice but that's really the limit of what you can do. It seems that the management are happy with the current margin of error and so there is your answer.